# How to transform one column to much column on matrix using Fortran 90

Tags: matrix, fortran, transform, gfortran, fortran90

I have one column (im = 160648) and row (jm = 1). I want to transform that to a matrix with sizes (im = 344) and (jm=467)

my program code is

```
  program matrix
  parameter (im=160648, jm=1)
  dimension h(im,jm)
  integer::h
  open (1,file="Hasil.txt", status='old')
  open (2,file="HasilNN.txt", status='unknown')
  do i=1,jm
         read(1,*)(h(i,j)),j=1,jm)
  end do

  do i=1,im
         write(2,33)(h(i,j),j=1,jm)
  end do
33 format(1x, 344f10.6)
  end program matrix
```

the error code that appears when `read(1,*)(h(i,j)),j=1,jm)`

> the data type is floating data.

Comment: The syntax error to which I refer is in `(h(i,j)),j=1,jm)`, with that extra `)` after `h(i,j)`.  I've voted to close this question as a simple typo.  There's also the fact that `h` is integer, but treated as real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your read loop is:

```
  do i=1,jm
     read(1,*)(h(i,j)),j=1,jm)
  end do
```

Shouldn't `do i=1,jm` be `do i=1,im` ?
This would imply there are "im" records (lines) in the formatted text file Hasil.txt, which your question suggests.

`read(1,*)(h(i,j)),j=1,jm)` implies each record (line of text) has "jm" values, which is 1 value per line. Is this what the file looks like ? (An unknown number of blank lines will be skipped with this `read (lu,*) ...` statement.)

You appear to be wanting to write this information to another file; HasilNN.txt using `33 format (1x, 344f10.6)` which suggests 3441 characters per line, although your write statement will write only 1 value per line (as jm=1). This would be a very long line for a text file and probably difficult to manage outside the program. If you did wish to do this, you could achieve this with an implied do loop, such as:

```
write(2,33) ((h(i,j),j=1,jm),I=1,im)
```

A few comments:

using jm = 1 implies each row has only one value, which could be equivalently represented as a 1d vector "dimension h(im)", negating the need for j

File unit numbers 1 and 2 are typically reserved unit numbers for screen/keyboard. You would be better using units 11 and 12.

When devising this code, you need to address the record structure in the 2 files, as a simple vector could be used. You can control the line length with the format. A format of (1x,8f10.6) would create a record of 81 characters, which would be much easier to manage.

Format descriptor f10.6 also limits the range of values you can manage in the files. Values >= 1000 or <= -100 will overflow this format, while values smaller than 1.e-6 will be zero.

As @francescalus has noted, you have declared "h" as integer, but use a real format descriptor. This will produce an "Error : format-data mismatch" and has to be changed to what is expected in the file.

You should consider what you wish to achieve and adjust the code.